# ANTLR4 memory cleanup

Tags: memory-leaks, antlr, antlr4

Is it possible to desallocate/reset/compress the memory allocated by ANTLR?

I already use `ParserATNSimulator.clearDFA()`, but some huge objects are still allocated (e.g., `ArrayPredictionContext`, `SingletonPredictionContext`).

My program alternates parsing and computation phases. Between two parsing phases, I would like to reduce the memory footprint of ANTLR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I replace the cache of the parser and lexer, there is no more path between these data structures and some static fields. Therefore the garbage collector can collect them.

```
lexer.setInterpreter(new LexerATNSimulator(lexer, lexer.getATN(), lexer.getInterpreter().decisionToDFA, new PredictionContextCache()));
parser.setInterpreter(new ParserATNSimulator(parser, parser.getATN(), parser.getInterpreter().decisionToDFA, new PredictionContextCache()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. The answer is no I would say at this time. I will add an issue at https://github.com/antlr/antlr4.